# Is Luther a property mogul?

Tags: luther

In the BBC crime drama *Luther*, does DCI John Luther flip houses or does he have a property portfolio? We only ever see him living in houses that need a little bit of decorating in various styles (upmarket terrace, high rise flat).

Comment: Are you sure? One of the fancy flats was Alice's not his. His house in the first season was a really shabby place as far as I remember.

Comment: @Luciano are you familiar with house flipping or London?

Comment: Yup, both. But we don't see him renovating any of the places or even talking about it, for all we know he could just be renting and moving around - the rent is also paid weekly right?

Comment: @Luciano We don't see him buying car and rarely eating or going to the toilet. He would earn good money but doesn't seem to spend it. Also what relevance or paying rent weekly?

Comment: Well, you're not asking about cars and toilet... Rent paid weekly means he can move more often, with just 4 weeks notice to end the tenancy. But in the series there's nothing that shows he has a property portfolio, or anything that would indicate he flips houses.

Comment: Perhaps he prefers to save money on rent to spend on his wardrobe!

Comment: @Paulie_D. Joking? He's been wearing the same coat for ever